# Can I use Javascript to save a file to the user's file system in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, safari

I understand that this is possible in Chrome and Opera, using the HTML5 FileWriter API, but this is not supported for Firefox and Safari. Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give enough details for a good answer ... things like

- Is this a one-time download
- Do you need to read-back this information?

I'm going to address the question, as you asked it:

Yes, there is a way to save a file to the local file system on many of the newer browsers, but it can't be down automatically by using the  `HTML5 download` attribute.

The user-experience is much the same as downloading other types of files.

More details can be found here:

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/08/html5-how-to-create-downloads-on-fly.html